# New Array from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my array

```
array(

    [0] => array(

        [unique_id]   => us - B00SM1YGS6
        [module_id]   => Amazon
        [create_date] => 2017 - 02 - 2101:39:35
        [price]       => 489.00
        [post_id]     => 3127)

    [1] => array(

        [unique_id]   => us - B01G0EURDY
        [module_id]   => Amazon
        [create_date] => 2017 - 02 - 1905:31:43
        [price]       => 799.00
        [post_id]     => 3112)

    [2] => array(
        [unique_id]   => us - B01FZZX9VG
        [module_id]   => Amazon
        [create_date] => 2017 - 02 - 1905:31:43
        [price]       => 199.75
        [post_id]     => 3112,
    ),
)
```

Now I want to make a new array which will hold the [unique_id] as key and prices as value

But in my array I have same unique_id repeated , so eventually I need something like this

```
array(
    [us - B00SM1YGS6] => array(price1, price2, price3)
    [us - B01G0EURDY] => array(price1, price2, price3),
)
```

How to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: show the array with repeated `unique_id`

Comment: here is full array http://kostanyan.com/final.php

Comment: can you show us what youve tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is more optimised way of doing it,

```
$temp = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $temp[$value['unique_id']][] = $value['price']; 
}
print_r($temp);
```

Give it a try, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$res=[];
foreach ($array as $val) {
    $res[$val['unique_id']] = isset($res[$val['unique_id']]) ? $res[$val['unique_id']] : [];
    array_push($res[$val['unique_id']], $val['price']);
}

print_r($res);
```

Comment: @HakobKostanyan I have  tried my code and its working perfectly..... Can you recheck ... have you copied code correctly...

Comment: sorry my bad, accidentally add a comma- it' working like a charm. Big thanks